# Sybase ASE - xmlvalidate with xml schema

Tags: xsd, sap-ase, xml-validation

I receive inputs to a procedure as xml and I've prepared the xml schema and would like to validate the input with the schema and throw an error if the input doesn't comply. I am trying to use xmlvalidate() option 'schemavalidate=yes' but couldn't figure out where to store my xml schema. The examples indicate a http url as the xml schema but should I host my xml schema? or should I store it as a database "text" column? Could someone guide me how to store and use the xml schema to use xmlvalidate()? We are at Sybase ASE 15.7

Appreciate your help!

---

Just adding the below question as hurdled in my next step on this:

I've hosted my xml schema and trying to use xmlvalidate as below:

```
xmlvalidate(@purgeTableInfo, option 'schemavalidate=yes,  nonamespaceschemalocation="http://myhost:5000/purgeschema"')
```

The required access to this purge schema has been provided to the unix box/login that hosts the database. We are able to ping to "myhost" from the unix box on which sybase is running. But, I am still getting the below error.

```
"XMLVALIDATE(): XML parser fatal error <<An exception occurred!
Type:NetAccessorException, Message:Could not create the socket for URL
'{0}'. Error={1>> at line 0, offset 0.
Sybase error code=14702
Severity Level=16, State=0, Transaction State=0"
```

Does anyone know what would be the reason and how should I go about fixing this?

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30020.1570/html/xmlb/BCEJGHEE.htm), to validate against a dtd, your schema needs to be hosted.  Your xml should be stored in a text column in the database, not your xml schema.  There are a number of examples in the documents, which should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I've hosted my xml schema and tried xmlvalidate but facing some issues. I've edited my question to include this error. Could you help me on this?

Comment: From here it's out of my area. You may want to try the SAP Community Network, as many of the Sybase/SAP engineers answer questions over there.  - http://scn.sap.com/community/sybase-adaptive-server-enterprise/content  (gave you the wrong link before..this one is correct).